# Can't fetch data on next page (React JS)

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Loading } from './loading';

function News({ pageSize }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    article: [],
    page: 1
  }
    )


  const getUsers = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    let res = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=79b02b430c1946cd9c505d3f91d7aec6&page=1&pageSize=${pageSize}`);
    setState({article: res.data.articles})
    setIsLoading(false)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers()
  }, [])


  const handleNext = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    let res = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=79b02b430c1946cd9c505d3f91d7aec6&page=${state.page + 1}&pageSize=${pageSize}`);
    setState({article: res.data.articles, page: state.page + 1})
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  
  let data = Array.from(state.article)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>News</h2>
      <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
      {isLoading && <Loading />}
      {!isLoading && data.map((elements) => {
        return (
          <div key={elements.url} style={{ marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
            <div> {elements.description} </div>
            <div>{new Date(elements.publishedAt).toGMTString()}</div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default News;
```

When I take states separately for data and page, I'm able to display next page's data. But now that I've created one state to manage multiple objects, it displays back first page's data instead of next page's data. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Pls help me!

Ignore the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  const getUsers = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    let res = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=79b02b430c1946cd9c505d3f91d7aec6&page=1&pageSize=${pageSize}`);
    setState({...state, article: res.data.articles})
    setIsLoading(false)
  };
```

Comment: One more thing, is there any other way to display data without using Array.from method?

Comment: @SameerI u can use console.log(...state.article)